# Get userID using CSOM powershell

Tags: powershell, user, csom

I want to get the User ID using PowerShell CSOM

I know its `$replacedUser =$web.EnsureUser("domainName\Account")` server side but I don't know how to do it client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$replacedUser =$Context.Web.EnsureUser(domain\USER)
```

this worked

Answer (score 2):

Should work more or less the same:

```
$identity = $web.EnsureUser($user)
$ctx.Load($identity)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```